# Storing n x m matrix in string

Tags: c#, string, matrix

This is my DataTable:

```
| 1 0 1 0 ...|
| 0 1 0 1 ...|
| 1 0 1 0 ...|
| . . . . ...|
```

I want to store this data in database in string form, something like this:

```
1010 0101 1010... or 1010;0101;1010... etc...
```

Also I need to read it back into DataTable.

There is a Matrix library at c# but it didnt help me. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to store multiple values in a single string in the database? That's against  all rules of normalization. You should do the opposite, if you have a somehow separated string in your app you should split it to multiple values before you store it in database(f.e. as multiple records in a relation table).

Comment: Because this dimensions can be more than 100. and its just a pattern of fabric. so this way is more logical to do for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have already a DB structure that has a textblob in it, your DataTable types are integers only being 0 and 1 and no nulls:

Store in DB from your DataTable called dataTable

```
StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow myRow = dataTable.Rows[i];
    foreach(object item in myRow.ItemArray)
    {
        if(item is int)
        {
            finalString.Append(item.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            //Error
        }
    }
    finalString.Append(";");
}

//TODO Write here your query where you store the finalString.ToString() in the DB
```

Load from DB assuming you have already the string from the DB as patternToLoad:

```
string[] rows = patternToLoad.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
DataTable newDT = new DataTable();
if(rows.Length > 0)
{
    int numOfColumns = rows[0].Length;
    //Since the matrix is not sparse all rows have the same length, so we just create the layout
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfColumns; i++)
    {
        newDT.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(int));
    }
    //Now go through all rows in string format and fill the actual DataTable
    foreach(string currentRow in rows)
    {
        DataRow newRow = newDT.NewRow();
        for(int j = 0; j < numOfColumns; j++)
        {
            newRow[j] = currentRow[j] = '1' ? 1 : 0;
        }
        newDT.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
}
```

You can make this a lot prettier but this gives you the general idea what to do. I have ommitted also a lot of chaecks that should go into  production code to keep it compact.